# For Loop Container SSIS AssignExpression

Tags: sql-server, for-loop, ssis, etl

I have table with columns  Start date and end date and i need to enter 
values for 2 years.I created a for loop  and I am trying to load values  for 
every month.

For Example, My first input  start Date is `10/12/2016` end date `11/11/2016`. It 
should be incremented with one month and inserted into table for 2 years.

**For Loop Container**

*InitExpression:* `@windowStart="10/12/2016"`

*Evalexpression:* `@WindowStart<@windowMaxdate`

*AssignExpression:* `@windowStart= Dateadd("mm",1,@windowStart)`

**Execute sql task**

*SQL command:*

```
Insert into dbo.datetemp 
(WindowStart,WindowEnd ) values (?,?)
```

My problem is i am not getting values what i am expected and its just 
returning same `windowstart` and `windowend` for every record. And loop is not coming to stop.

[image]

Comment: have you thought of inserting the rows in one ExecuteSQL task instead of a loop?

Comment: i want do this using for loop only i dont want to use direct sql statement

Comment: Post a screenshot of your ForLoop container properties so we can see what you are doing there.

Comment: Hi Tab, i just added image , it was in a link. can you see that.

Comment: Just a comment: this is a very convoluted way of achieving this.It would be much simpler to just write a piece of T-SQL and execute it. If you are doing data activities, it's important to avoid loops and procedural code. It is important to understand set based approaches.

Answer (score 1):

Guys i got the solution.

I have added a expression task inside for loop after execute sql task

```
@[User::WindowStart] = (DT_WSTR,24)(DT_DBTIMESTAMP) dateadd("mm",1, 
(@[User::WindowStart]) )
```

instead adding this expression in Assign expression in for loop editor.

Answer (score 0):

**You are passing a string value to a `@windowStart`.**

Create a variable `@StartDate` of type Datetime with the value `2016-12-10`. And use the following  expression:

*InitExpression:* `@windowStart= @StartDate`

Also make sure that `@windowStart` and `@windowMaxdate` are of type `DateTime`

Also check this similar question for more information:

- [How do I loop through date values stored as numbers within For Loop container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13257068/how-do-i-loop-through-date-values-stored-as-numbers-within-for-loop-container)

Comment: its the same thing i am getting only one record into table. and the loop is not stoping execution. where execute sql task inserted only one record.